# Mvp4g multiple view

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp, mvp4g

I have implemented multiple Presenter in mvp4g using

```
@Presenter(..., multiple = true)
```

How can I create multiple instances of view for each new presenter?
I need to add Tabs on TabPanel, each one will be the new view.

Should I need to use setView(new View) method in Presenter to create a new Instance of View?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

> I found a bug in my code, so have no problem now. Mvp4g  new View instance creates when new Instance of Presenter creates. Don't forget, that that each event that handles by Presenter with tag "multiple" is fired for each Presenter instance. So you need to implement some checks when handling event

Comment: I found a bug in my code, so have no problem now. Mvp4g  new View instance creates when new Instance of Presenter creates. Don't forget, that that each event that handles by Presenter with tag "multiple" is fired for each Presenter instance. So you need to implement some checks when handling event